# returning a value from postgresql delete that impacts 0 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

is it possible to return a value from a `delete` statement in postgres when no rows were deleted?

Example:

```sql
-- Create a table
create table dummy(id int);
```

```sql
delete from dummy where id = 999 returning <ANSWER HERE>
-- Desired output = "1"
```

What I've tried:

```sql
delete from dummy where id = 999 returning 1
-- returns: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of using `RETURNING` after a `DELETE` command is that - `RETURNING` gets only deleted records. If the `RETURNING` will get records on the not deleted process, then this is will be an illogical or abnormal situation.

But, you can use a logical process for doing this. For example, using the `UNION` command we can add one record to the result of `RETURNING`. So, when records are deleted we are getting deleted records + one record of `UNION`. When records are not be deleted we get only one record of the `UNION` command.

Example query for about this process:

```
with del_table as 
(
    delete from test.test 
    where id = 4100 
    returning id, title
)
select id, title from del_table
union all 
select 100, 'test';

Result:
id      title
----------------
4100    TestData
100     test
```